# Rails - Exclude a column on create only

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Can we exclude column to be added to INSERT statement while creating a record?

For instance, table `students` has `id`, `name`, `skip_me` columns.

```
s = Student.new(id: 1, name: 'Test')
s.save

# produces

INSERT INTO students(id, name, skip_me) VALUES(1, 'Test', null)
```

While what I want INSERT statment like this without the `skip_me` column:

```
INSERT INTO students(id, name) VALUES(1, 'Test')
```

I have tried to set the `s.attributes` to remove the `skip_me` from the attributes but it's doesn't work either.

I just want to skip the column on CREATE only and not from SELECT and UPDATE, so I can't use the `ignored_columns`.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a complete answer, but you can try overriding `attributes_for_create` [method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b13a5cb83ea00d6a3d71320fd276ca21049c2544/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb#L468) in your model.

This is how PK is removed from what eventually becomes the INSERT query.

Your `Student` class would have something like

```
  private

  def attributes_for_create(attribute_names)
    super.reject { |a| a == "some_attribute" }
  end
```